# Two wall switches and remote ceiling fan/light questions

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, repair, switch

I am installing a Harbor Breeze ceiling fan with light and wanting to use two wall switches and the remote to adjust the fan speed. Looking at the ceiling, I see the following for an old ceiling fan/light.

-Blue from light/fan twisted with black
-white from light/fan twisted with brown
-black from light/fan twisted with red
-green ground from light/fan twisted with cooper.

The remote box on the new fan shows the following:
-white AC In N
-black AC In L
On the other side:
-White To Motor in
-Black to Motor L
-Blue for light

The way the switches are wired is the switch controlling the fan on and off has a red wire going to it.

The manual shows:

Connect all GROUND (GREEN) wires from fan (on downrod (A), if applicable, and mounting bracket (C)) to BARE/GREEN supply wire from ceiling.
Connect BLACK wire (labeled AC IN L) from remote control receiver (O) to BLACK supply wire from ceiling.
Connect WHITE wire (labeled AC IN N) from remote control receiver (O) to WHITE supply wire from ceiling.
Connect WHITE wire (labeled TO MOTOR N) from remote control receiver (O) to WHITE wire from motor housing (D).
Connect BLACK wire (labeled TO MOTOR L) from remote control receiver (O) to BLACK wire from motor housing (D).
Connect BLUE wire (labeled FOR LIGHT) from remote control receiver (O) to BLUE wire from motor housing (D)

Is it possible to have one switch control the light and the other control the fan and I can use the remote to adjust the fan speed?  Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the existing box? Are you wedded to the remote that came to your fan, or is a different remote an option?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  You're thinking about those smart switches again.. stay safe.

Comment: Hopefully, the added pic will help.  If not, I will take the fan down and retake.  Also, the remote came with the fan/light.  I am specifically putting up the Harbor Breeze Beach Creek.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: Please see the added pic of the switch.  Thanks!

Comment: @CKV -- thanks for the pic!  How open are you to the idea of getting a different remote? (It's probably possible to do what you're asking with the stock remote, but it could lead to mildly confusing fan behavior, which can be avoided if you're willing to ditch the stock remote for something else instead)

Comment: A different remote would be fine.  Let me know what you would recommend.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### You'll want to switch the fan switch out for a wallbox-type remote setup

The thing with the remotes that come with fans is they don't play nice with anything else that wants to control the fan; a few manufacturers provide battery-powered wall-mount remotes, but anything beyond that is out of the question.  Since you have separate wall switches with separate gangs for the fan and light, though, you have some flexibility in how you do this, and my recommendation would be a Lutron Caseta fan controller.  This mounts in the wallbox instead of the current switch for the fan, and provides both wall-switch and remote control of the fan, including speed switching, without the need for any further parts.  You'll have to take the old Harbor Breeze remote receiver out of the picture if you go this path though.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I was looking over the install guide https://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/0301911.pdf.  What am I connecting the red wire from the switch to?  Also, is there anything I am capping off and not using in either the switches or ceiling?  Thanks!

Comment: @CKV -- the red wire I guess would be the line in then, and you shouldn't have to cap anything off in either place once you get rid of the old remote receiver